# Temp File In PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, optimization

My db size is growing up to 41GB but when I create a backup it becomes 2.4 / 2.5GB, Why this much difference?

I have performed some vaccum, Reindexing etc. but still the size is not shrinking and **it is showing 19 GB temp file** but when I check in `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\10\data\base\pgsql_tmp` the folder is empty..

**How can I delete those temp files?** **Is there a way to reduce my DB size?**

**EDIT**

[image: db stat result]

Query to get temp files

```
SELECT temp_files AS "Temporary files"
     , temp_bytes AS "Size of temporary files"
    FROM   pg_stat_database db;
```

Comment: `pg_dump` does not include index data, additionally, the custom format compresses the backup. So if you have a lot of indexes, it is expected that a dump taken with `pg_dump` is a lot smaller than the actual database size.

Comment: Unrelated, but: it is not a good idea to put the data directory into `c:\Program Files` on Windows.

Comment: Please show the queries and query results that lead you to your conclusion. Don't add that information as a comment, edit the question.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The values in `pg_stat_database` are cummulative since the server was started, so it's **not** the number of bytes **currently** used. It's the number of bytes used since the statistics were reset.

As this is a cumulative number, it will increase constantly and will never shrink unless you reset the statistics.

You can reset those statistics (as the superuser) using

```
select pg_stat_reset();
```

It seems that your queries are indeed using many temp files and temp space. That could indicate that you have not given Postgres enough memory (e.g. `work_mem` or `temp_buffers`)  But that is a different question.

Those temp file are also not part of a database dump as they are only used during query execution.